# Data visualisation - how to visualize relative size of data charts related to each dimension rather than the overall amount of replies

Tags: user-expectation, info-visualisation, data-analysis

Currently, I redesign a data-driven platform and what is confusing is a presentation of data on a comparison view. As you can see the bar's size is relative for each value (rows), but not relative to overall data. Each dimension (row) has a different total amount so that's also not relative /proportional in comparison to another dimension(rows). I'm concerned about how to visualize data to make it more clear for the user. Currently for instance in the example below the value of 3 is more than double the size of a chart with 8 replies. So it's totally confusing...[image: example]

[image: 2 EXAMPLES OF DATA VISUALIZATION]

Comment: so... each row has 5 visualizations; those are related to each other, but not the row below it, correct? What is being compared in this case?

Comment: that's a rating. on the example, above you see a 5-star rating, another chart has ie. 10 point rating. you compare the ratings between ie, departments/ offices in different countries. That's why important is to compare them. What's important each of them has a different amounts of replies/ answers. that's what creates confusion. For the example above ie. number 3 on 5th row is bigger than number eight on 3rd row. I thought to maybe compare them by percentage overall and additionally on a side add the amount of answers/ replies?

Comment: Is this statement correct?: 4 people gave 1 start to Dimension 1

Comment: Also, what is the relationship between Dimension 1 and Dimension 2? Does it matter?

Comment: Nicolas Hung. Yes, indeed you are right :) I have also 10 point scale to prepare :P The relationship between dimension one/two is that ie. it's different departments/offices which the user would compare.

Comment: I actually prepared 2 versions for data visualization but I'm not sure which is best.I like the stacked bar chart because PLUSES - It's simple and readable. Even if the number of dimensions will increase it won't take too much space  MINUSES - user will be able to preview the exact percentage of every rating and amount of replies by hovering on a bar - so the data won't be displayed before that.

Comment: IDEA 2 - data visualization by Combined Charts type. The axis represents percentage  PLUSES  - the user is able to preview all interesting data and simply compare it with different variables. Moreover, the percentage and amount of replies are visible so it's no need for a tooltip. This allows the user to quickly compare data MINUSES -  if we'll have a lot of data to compare it with like more than 5 (in the example it's 5) it can be really confusing and it can start to be harder to read

Comment: I uploaded the example image to the question above

Answer (score 0):

The challenge with data visualization design is often centred around how to present the key information as clear as possible without compromising the integrity and accuracy of the underlying data.

There is no easy answer to the question because often you want to combine one or more datasets and/or views of the data (for whatever reason), and you need to find the right trade-off between showing enough information for it to be useful, but not too much so that it becomes overwhelming.

I think the better solution is to break down the overall data visualization into smaller chunks, or to create some interactions that allow you to filter or change the views so that there is less information to process. This will also give you a cleaner design and more focus for the audience.

But you are probably working with a few different sets of requirements and constraints, so just keep in mind that it is about getting the right balance rather than something that is going to solve the problem 100% of the time.